# How do I animate multiple dynamically generated DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, animation, hover

This may be useful to see where I am coming from.
[Jquery nested each problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005006/jquery-nested-each-problem)

I am adding `divs` to the page with this code:

```
jQuery("#list").append(
    jQuery("<div>")
        .attr("id", "Entry")
        .html(html)
);
```

`html` is just a string containing some text and an anchor.

I am trying to animate the new divs - there are multiple div's with the id `#Entry`.

Here's my code:

```
jQuery("#Entry").hover(function(){  
    jQuery(this)
    .animate({
        width:"50%",
        fontSize: "30px",
        opacity: 0.3,
        borderwidth: "15px"
    }, 500);  
});
```

The above is in my `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ }` function, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you are adding more than 1 `<div>` with that id, you are doing it wrong. `id` attributes should (must) be UNIQUE in a document. Having more than 1 element with the same `id` will make Javascript go haywire because it is not supposed to happen. It would be the equivalent of two people with the same social security number. :) The common and best practice when it comes to groups of elements is to give them all a class and select them that way.

Past that, you should look into the [`live`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) function, which does what you want. Essentially, when you run a piece of code on your document ready, it is being executed against the *current* state of the document. In other words, only elements that exist at that point in time (that match the selector provided) will be bound to the event you provided. The `live` function was created as a way to get around this. Another solution would be to run the binding code again after you add a new `<div>`, but that is not as clean as just using `live`, which supports the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events you're going to need to do the `hover`.

Comment: So live doesn't support hover. It does support mouseover, mouseout. However, I have an anchor in my div, so when I move along my anchor it registers a mouseover event that bubbles up, so I get a flicker that is ridiculous. It seems lots of people are in this predicament from a google search, live doesn't support hover, mouseenter, or mouseleave so we are left with mouseover, but that has this problem. Hmm.

Comment: In that case, just do the alternative I said; run the code after you add the div.

Answer (score 0):

live() supports all events including custom events in the latest jQuery...